# Is it possible to change column header and filter a column in one command?

Tags: bash, awk

I'm using awk to filter interesting lines in a large text file before reading it with a statistical software.
Here is some dummy data

```
printf 'VEGETABLE_NAME,RECIPE_NAME,OBSCURE_CODE\ncarrot,cake,1\ncarrot,soup,1\npotato,cake,2\nspinach,soup,1' > dummydata.dat
```

I have managed to :

1. Change the column header

   ```
   $ awk -F, 'NR==1 {$0="vegetable,recipe,code"} 1' dummydata.dat
   vegetable,recipe,code
   carrot,cake,1
   carrot,soup,1
   potato,cake,2
   spinach,soup,1
   ```
2. Filter for product code 1

   ```
   $ awk -F, '$3 ~ /^1/' dummydata.dat
   carrot,cake,1
   carrot,soup,1
   spinach,soup,1
   ```

But when I try to combine both commands, the result doesn't include the column header:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1 {$0="vegetable,recipe,code"} $3 ~ /^1/' dummydata.dat
carrot,cake,1
carrot,soup,1
spinach,soup,1
```

Comment: the `1` in first code prints `$0`... the combination you tried, `$0` is assigned but not printed... when `$3 ~ /^1/` condition is satisfied, `$0` is printed... a simple change should work... `awk -F, 'NR==1 {print "vegetable,recipe,code"} $3 ~ /^1/'`

Comment: also for string comparison, just use `$3 == "1"` no need regex.. `$3 ~ /^1/` will match `11` or `10asad` and so on..

Comment: sorry don't intend to hijack your question, wondering would this be possible with just grep what you want and prepend the header while saving to a another file?

Comment: @Sundeep I actually need a regex for the original, more complex dataset, but of course with this simple example string comparison is enough.

Comment: @UlugToprak `awk` is easier to use when searching for a match in a field separated data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your approach, you didn't get the column header because it will print lines
only based on the condition

```
$3 ~ /^1/
```

If that evaluates to  true`(1)`, then print else`(0)` don't. Unfortunately it evaluates false for the header.

Below is my try

```
awk -v FS="," 'BEGIN{print "vegetable,recipe,code"}NR>1 && $3==1'
vegetable,recipe,code
carrot,cake,1
carrot,soup,1
spinach,soup,1
```

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to use `-F` go with `-v FS=","`.

Comment: Thanks, "man awk" mentions the `-F` option and doesn't specify why it would be preferable to use `-v FS=","` can you elaborate?

Comment: In the end, I used the code from @sundeep's comment, but your answer works fine as well. It seems the `BEGIN` statement is not needed.

Comment: @PaulRougieux .Simply because `-F` is not supported on certain implemetations but `-v FS=` is portable.

Comment: @PaulRougieux: Comment above is based on some vague memory and may not be established as a fact. To my surprise `awk` and its GNU counterpart `gawk` both supports `-F` option. Adding to that [\[ Unix AWK \]](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/awk/) manpage says `if -F sepstring and -v FS=sepstring are both used, it is unspecified whether  the  FS  assignment resulting from -F sepstring is processed in command line order or is processed after the last -v FS=sepstring.` That makes me think it is good to stick on with `-v` option for some consistency.

Comment: @sjsam `-F` is the preferred method to set FS alone from the commandline (simply for brevity) and is supported by all awks except old, broken awk (/bin/awk on Solaris) which should never be used by anyone for any reason. The only reason to use `-v FS='...'` is if you are also setting `-v OFS='...'` to a different value than `FS` and want to use the same method for both for consistency.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting `$0` for `NR==1` but that record never gets printed anywhere.

You can make a small change in your script to make it:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{print "vegetable,recipe,code"} $3 ~ /^1$/' dummydata.dat

vegetable,recipe,code
carrot,cake,1
carrot,soup,1
spinach,soup,1
```